# Can we zoom to a KML placemark object using the KML object ID in google earth plugin API?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

Can we zoom to a KML placemark object's (polygon/line/point) extent using the object ID in google earth plugin API? We can change the style of the KML object using it's ID, in the same way is it possible to zoom to that KML object's extent?

Regards,
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there are quite a few ways to do this.

Really the best way would depend on a few things, such as your current set up, how you have defined your objects (in Kml or via the API), etc.

In general possibly your best bet would be to use something like the [GEarthExtensions utility library](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/). The Util class contains the [flyToObject](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsUtilReference#flyToObject(obj,_options)) method which...

> Flies to an object; if the object is a feature and has an explicitly
>   defined abstract view, that view is used. Otherwise, attempts to
>   calculate a bounds view of the object and flies to that (assuming
>   options.boundsFallback is true).

The main feature here being that the bounds calculations for the various types of geometry in the API are there for you.

If you wanted to roll your own then you should definitely take a look at the code in the extension library as well as at the [accessors](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/accessors) in the API.